# How can we make Squid do a reverse nslookup?

Tags: bind, squid

We all know that `access.log` file logs the access Info of Squid:

```
1286536351.746  41762 192.168.1.17 TCP_MISS/200 5340945 GET http://v15.lscache3.c.youtube.com/videoplayback? - DIRECT/122.160.120.150 video/x-flv
1286536351.746  41762 192.168.1.18 TCP_MISS/200 5340945 GET http://v15.lscache3.c.youtube.com/videoplayback? - DIRECT/122.160.120.150 video/x-flv
```

We all also know that Squid use the file `/etc/resolv.conf` to determine the DNS server it is dealing with, so if we want Squid to deal with a local DNS server we enter the local DNS server in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.

What if the local DNS server has a record like this (in its reverse zone (1.168.192.in-addr.arpa)):

```
$TTL 60 ; 1 minute
17          PTR Mark.
18          PTR Mike.
```

Can I configure Squid to do a reverse lookup (asking about the name of the IP address in the log file) and add the names to the `access.log` record, for example:

I want to make this record:

```
1286536351.746  41762 192.168.1.17 ......
```

to be something  like this:

```
1286536351.746  41762 192.168.1.17 Mark ......
```

How can I reach this?

Can I use Squid logformats like `%>a` and `%>A` to get what I want?

Comment: This sounds like what you're asking for: http://www.packtpub.com/article/configuring-squid-use-dns-servers. Additionally you could forgo this and use a post-mortem program to insert the hostnames into an already existing `access.log` file. This file should be in the standard Apache "combined" format and there are a number of scripts that will do this floating around the web.

Comment: `for every request received from a client, Squid needs to resolve the domain name before it can contact the target web server. For this purpose, Squid can either use the built-in internal DNS client or, external DNS program to resolve the hostnames` , that what the page you give me have,  but that isn't what I want, I want Squid to do a `reverse` lookup @slm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method would be to make use of this directive in the `squid.conf` file to get the log file to show FQDNs instead of the IPs:

```
log_fqdn on
```

*Source: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/log_fqdn/*

But this will omit the `<IP> <Name>` format that you're showing in your question. For that if you look at the documentation for the `logformat` directive the following default formats are listed:

```
logformat squid      %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %[un %Sh/%<a %mt
logformat common     %>a %[ui %[un [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %>Hs %<st %Ss:%Sh
logformat combined   %>a %[ui %[un [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %>Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh
logformat referrer   %ts.%03tu %>a %{Referer}>h %ru
logformat useragent  %>a [%tl] "%{User-Agent}>h"
```

And these options are listed as parameters that you can use in building up your own format:

```
>a  Client source IP address
>A  Client FQDN
```

So I would expect that you could put this together to get the format that you're asking about.

#### References

- [Squid configuration directive logformat](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/)

Comment: @Networker - glad it solved your issue. Sorry it took so long to figure it out 8-).

Comment: In 2020 the "log_fqdn" option is obsolate, deprecated, and will go away.  Modifying the  logformat line is the current answer.